# Protocols: Why is @ObjC required for conformance checking and optional requirements?

Tags: design-patterns, swift, programming-languages, protocols, option-type

The [Swift documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html) says the following about *protocols*:

> You can check for protocol conformance only if your protocol is marked
>   with the @objc attribute, as seen for the HasArea protocol above. This
>   attribute indicates that the protocol should be exposed to Objective-C
>   code and is described in Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C. Even
>   if you are not interoperating with Objective-C, you need to mark your
>   protocols with the @objc attribute if you want to be able to check for
>   protocol conformance.
>
> Note also that @objc protocols can be adopted only by classes, and not
>   by structures or enumerations. If you mark your protocol as @objc in
>   order to check for conformance, you will be able to apply that
>   protocol only to class types.

and

> Optional protocol requirements can only be specified if your protocol
>   is marked with the @objc attribute. Even if you are not interoperating
>   with Objective-C, you need to mark your protocols with the @objc
>   attribute if you want to specify optional requirements.
>
> Note also that @objc protocols can be adopted only by classes, and not
>   by structures or enumerations. If you mark your protocol as @objc in
>   order to specify optional requirements, you will only be able to apply
>   that protocol to class types.

---

Why cannot *pure Swift protocols* (non-`@objc`) be checked for conformance. Why don't they have optional requirements? Can anybody guess the underlying language design reason?

I expect that at some undetermined (probably far away) time in the future Apple will slowly reimplement and replace *Cocoa* and *CocoaTouch* with libraries programmed purely in Swift. At that time, if we wan't to avoid using any Obj-C related stuff, should we avoid using optional protocol requirements and protocol checks conformance in our code?

If so, what's Swift's idiomatic way of achieving similar patterns without using `@objc`? (E.g., a delegate with optional methods.)

---

For example, this simple use case cannot be implemented with non-`@objc` protocols (and `Printable`, `DebugPrintable` and `Streamable` are non-`@objc`:

```
import UIKit

let firstName = "John"
let lastName = "Appleseed"
let age = 33
let height = 1.74

let values: [Any] = [firstName, lastName, age, height]
let stringifiedValues = [String]()

for value in values
{
    if let pritanbleValue = value as? Printable
    {
        stringifiedValues.append(value.description)
    }
    else if let debugPrintableValue = value as? DebugPrintable
    {
        stringifiedValues.append(value.debugDescription)
    }
    else if let streamableValue = value as? Streamable
    {
        var string = ""
        streamableValue.writeTo(&string)
        stringifiedValues.append(string)
    }
    // etc.    
    else 
    {
        stringifiedValues.append("[NoStringRepresentation]")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*jckarter*, an Apple employee, said the following on an [Apple Developer Forums' thread](https://devforums.apple.com/message/1072650#1072650):

> This is a limitation of Swift's runtime. We intend to remove this restriction in a future release.

Answer (score 6):

Swift probably does not include enough runtime type information to check for protocol conformance. Protocols are really only a compile-time thing, and ObjC includes extra tables in the built product that aren't strictly necessary for running the program to allow determining conformance. Since @objc has to turn a class/protocol into something that ObjC understands, objects declared with this attribute get the additional metadata and probably other adapter data structures so ObjC won't notice they're not real ObjC.

The recommendation from Apple in ObjC has always been to check for the presence of individual methods, and not to look at the class or protocol, to permit duck typing and enable use of proxy objects. My guess is that this is the reason why the designers of Swift felt it was OK to leave out protocol runtime data in the default case, to encourage proper detection of features of a class.

As to how to use it: For the case of a protocol you're apparently supposed to use the `?` operator (which checks both whether the object exists and that it implements the given method). I don't know if the same works for system API, but given it's an ObjC class in that case, you can just call `foo.respondsToSelector("doFoo:")`.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughtful answer! However, I don't agree with the second paragraph. How can a delegator check for individual methods of its delegate unless its with Protocol's optional requirements? The third paragraph doesn't work for me, I'm asking about pure Swift code in an hypothetical ObjC-free code. A possibility I can think of is that this is just a missing feature right now and will be added later.

Comment: @RicardoSánchez-Sáez: Actually, no Cocoa APIS ever check for protocol conformance; they always check that the object responds to the particular selector being sent. It's easy to do this in Objective-C. In Swift, you just need to cast it to `AnyObject` to be able to use optional chaining or test the optional method. (Of course, if you are not sure that the object is an instance of the protocol, it is probably already `AnyObject`.)

Comment: You are right, maybe the delegate pattern was not a good example. However, I think that checking for protocol conformance is still useful. See the example I added to the question. You cannot use optional chaining for unknown methods on AnyObject without using selectors (and selectors don't have a place in pure Swift).