# Swift EXC_BAD_ACCESS when unwrapping optional weak property of protocol type

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, exc-bad-access

I have this code in my Xcode playground that gives me `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error on last line:

```
protocol SomeProtocol: class {
    func test()
}

class SomeClass: SomeProtocol {
    func test(){}
}

struct Weak<T: AnyObject> {
    weak var value: T?

    init(_ value: T) {
        self.value = value
    }
}

var value: SomeProtocol = SomeClass()
var w = Weak(value)

w.value?.test()  // EXC_BAD_ACCESS
```

If I add `@objc` to protocol definition than code executes without any errors:

```
import Foundation

@objc protocol SomeProtocol: class {
    func test()
}

class SomeClass: SomeProtocol {
    @objc func test(){}
}

struct Weak<T: AnyObject> {
    weak var value: T?

    init(_ value: T) {
        self.value = value
    }
}

var value: SomeProtocol = SomeClass()
var w = Weak(value)

w.value?.test()
```

I suspect that these lines of Apple documentation somehow relate to my case:

> Even if you are not interoperating with Objective-C, you need to mark
>   your protocols with the @objc attribute if you want to be able to
>   check for protocol conformance.

But I do not understand why it does not work without `@objc`. Could someone explain?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Protocols: Why is @ObjC required for conformance checking and optional requirements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26909974/protocols-why-is-objc-required-for-conformance-checking-and-optional-requireme)

Comment: I read this question, but it did not help me. I am not checking for protocol conformance and do not use `optional` requirements. So I completely do not understand why my code does not work.

Comment: "This is a limitation of Swift's runtime. We intend to remove this restriction in a future release." - according to Apple Developers.

Answer (score 1):

Swift currently does not handle using non-class types with generics well.

The actual location of the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` is when the result of `Weak(value)` is assigned to `var w`. You can see this by adding the `println` statements around the `var w = Weak(value)`.

To get around these problems with Swift you'll need to Box values with non-class types to use them with generics.

Hopefully in the next few versions of Swift Apple will fix these issues and we'll no longer need to box values.

```
final class Box<T> {
    private var value: T

    init(_ value: T) {
        self.value = value
    }

    var unbox: T {
        return value
    }
}

protocol SomeProtocol : AnyObject {
    func test()
}

class SomeClass: SomeProtocol {
    func test(){
        println("Test")
    }
}

struct Weak<T: AnyObject> {
    weak var value: T?

    init(_ value: T) {
        println("Weak Init Start")
        self.value = value
        println("Weak Init Stop")
    }
}

var value: SomeProtocol = SomeClass()

//Method in Question

println("Before Weak Init")
// var w = Weak(value) // EXC_BAD_ACCESS
println("After Weak Init")

//w.value?.test()


// Method with Box

var box = Box(value)
var w = Weak(box)

w.value?.unbox.test() // prints "Test"

w = Weak(Box(value))
w.value?.unbox.test() // nil, since nothing retains the Box(value) result
```